# Calculate elevation from rgb from png created from qgis

Tags: qgis, dem, srtm, png

I am using qgis to create a raster elevation image (png) from SRTM data. I need to create a png via qgis which I will then query to determine the rgb of particular pixels via php. How do I define a color scheme within qgis in a way that I can then use the same gradient to calculate the elevation of the pixel from the png?

Answer (score 1):

To be honest that is not a good way to do it.

**But** if you must then you could encode the value of the dem in the R (or G or B) element of the image by calculating `256*(value/maxValue)`. Your Php code could then reverse the calculation as `maxvalue*(pixel/256)`.

Comment: Thanks. I need to determine elevations between 0 and 5000m so 256 colours would give me 19m intervals which I guess is the resolution of th SRTM data so that would work I guess. So I just choose multiband colour from the style section of the layer property?

Comment: better to use a 32bit tiff and read out directly